# how to force a string value in html 5 'data' attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do you force a text value in an html 5 data attribute when accessing it in js?

I have a global app with a similar line of html:

```
<div class="slider" data-max="125" data-cost="10000" data-costtext="10.000">
```

the '.' in the text cost value is accurate for some languages. When accessing this value through jQuery js

```
$("div.slider","body").data("costtext")
```

you will get back `10`.

Is a re-write my only option?, like so:

```
<div class="slider" data-obj='{"max":125,"cost":10000,"costtext":"10.000"}'>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `attr("data-x")` to access the value and you'll have a `String`.

jQuery tries to deduce the type and automatically convert it from `String` when you use `data()`.

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise
>   it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string
>   without any attempt to convert it, use the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5).

Comment: excellent option.  saves me a rewrite of a lot of other code, without getting too messy.